# MYSQL Simple Query - Need Union Alternative

Tags: mysql, union

I have a MYSQL table called "registrations"

```
id    license           price     attachment_id (maps back to the same table)
33    Description A      10            35
34    Description B      15            0
35    Description C      18            0
36    Description D      5             37
37    Description E      10            0
```

I need to get the row where id = 33 and output **ANOTHER ROW** where the *attachment_id* column matches the "*id*" column in the same table.

So, the output should be:

```
id    license           price     attachment_id (maps back to the same table)
33    Description A      10            35
35    Description C      18            0
```

How can I do this without a UNION?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible:

```
select * from registrations where
id = 33 or id = (select attachment_id from resgistrations where id = 33)
```